# Simple correspondence analysis in Python

Tags: python, dimensionality-reduction, correspondence-analysis

How can I run simple correspondence analysis (CA) in Python? In the sklearn library, there only appears to be multiple correspondence analysis (MCA) and canonical correspondence analysis (CCA) options. However, my data is not categorical and does not need the additional linearity constraints applied by CCA.

My impression based on [this link on CCA](http://131.95.113.139/courses/multivariate/CCA.pdf) and [this one on MCA](https://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-MCA2007-pretty.pdf) is that regular CA cannot be applied by using one of the two other option.

Comment: A tutotrial: [tutorial to build a CA class](http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=2357)   And the canonical CA: [see also here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html)

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial looks great! On the other hand, is it possible to use the sklearn canonical CA for regular CA?

Comment: I will write an answer adding more resources !

Comment: Note that the CCA method in scikit-learn stands for canonical correlation analysis, which slightly differs from canonical correspondence analysis, see for a more detailed explanation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38629/difference-between-canonical-correpondence-analysis-and-canonical-correlation-an).

Answer (score 1):

For correspondence analysis you can use a package "prince" https://pypi.org/project/prince/ . It makes a plot from the data in a few steps. Although the drawback is that you (I) cannot see details of the calculated residuals for instance.